# Algorithm to compute $\zeta_p(n)$ at a positive integer.

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, algebraic-number-theory

Does anyone know any efficient algorithm to compute the $p$-adic expansion of $\zeta_p(n)$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \geq 3$, where $\zeta_p$ is the $p$-adic zeta function.

I also hope to implement the algorithm in Mathematica, does anyone know any Mathematica package for $p$-adic analysis?

Comment: What is the time-complexity of the algorithm you have currently? What have you tried? Research?

Comment: Currently I am still reading some $p$-adic analysis, so I don't know any algorithm. It's research in future.